# Android AppWidget and IntentService, same result from two different buttons

Tags: android, intentservice, android-appwidget

Android newbie here.  I have an app with one activity, and one AppWidget.  They both send commands to an IntentService.  The activity works just fine, but the AppWidget, which consists of two buttons, give the same result no matter which button i click.
Maybe I can't use an IntentService from an AppWidget like this...?  I'm just learning.  Any help would be appreciated.

My IntentService class:

```
public class RemoteIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "RemoteIntentService";

    public RemoteIntentService() {
        super("RemoteIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        String command = data.getString("command");
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: command = " + command);
    }
}
```

My AppWidget class:

```
public class RemoteWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String TAG = "RemoteWidget";

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.remote_widget);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            Intent intentButton1 = new Intent(context, RemoteIntentService.class);
            intentButton1.putExtra("command", "Button1");

            Intent intentButton2 = new Intent(context, RemoteIntentService.class);
            intentButton2.putExtra("command", "Button2");

            PendingIntent pendingButton1 = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intentButton1, 0);
            PendingIntent pendingButton2 = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intentButton2, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.remote_widget);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingButton1);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingButton2);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

The output when I click the two buttons on the AppWidget:

```
D/RemoteIntentService: onHandleIntent: command = Button1
D/RemoteIntentService: onHandleIntent: command = Button1
```

Comment: Post your layout xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intentButton1, 0)` (specifically, the `0` as the last parameter), extras do not get replaced per the [PendingIntent overview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by [Intent.filterEquals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)). If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per [Intent.filterEquals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)), then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.

They go into details on how to deal with them, although in your case you can change it so that each `PendingIntent` has a unique request codes (the second parameter):

```
PendingIntent pendingButton1 = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
    intentButton1, 0);
PendingIntent pendingButton2 = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1,
    intentButton2, 0);
```

This will cause Android to view them as two separate PendingIntents.